# BLTouch error causing bed and nozzle temp setpoints to change to zero

Tags: nozzle, bltouch, bed, temperature

I replaced my CR-10 motherboard with no problems and ran fine for a few weeks, then decided to add a BLTouch. BLTouch was enabled from the `config.h` during compile.

I had heating issues at first but eventually figured out I had the thermistors plugs swapped on the motherboard. In the past, I never used start and stop G-codes because I only printed printer upgrades off of Thingiverse while learning to print. My prints weren't starting until I learned more about G-codes and added `G29` and `G29` to my Cura start codes.

I tried a piece that I've printed before because I knew it worked ok. I preheated the bed and nozzle first, then started the print. The `G28` initiates and homes, then the `G29` does the 9 point bed leveling, then just sits there and does nothing.

### BLTouch behavior during the process

- BLTouch moves to "home" from center, with probe up and red light
- With the light still remaining red, BLTouch goes back to the center
- The BLTouch light turns blue once at the center, and drops the probe and lowers until probe touches and the light turns red
- Then raises again and the light turns blue, lowers again until probe touches bed then the light turns red again
- The light stays red and raises Z axis a little - and stays at center, still red
- The probe stays at center and red **until reaching preheating temps**
- **After selecting file** the probe moves to 9/9 points, with probe raised and blue light (drops probe and lowers until touching and turns red, then raises and turns blue)
- Once the **last probe location is checked**, BLTouch is still red and temperature settings from project file are set and heating starts
- The setpoints of bed and nozzle are reached (**successfully heated**)
- After heating, the setpoints switch to zero and temps start dropping towards the zero set point (**cooldown**) and never moves after that and shows status "Stopped"

### Pronterface - manual attempts

I connected through Pronterface so I could see the exact details.
When I run a `G28`, from Pronterface:

- It goes to lower corner and is still red
- Returns to the center, probe drops and turns blue
- A few seconds later it drops until touching the bed and turns red
- Raises up again and turns blue, then drops BLTouch again until it touches the bed and turns red
- Then raises up again, but stays red this time
- I get an error in Pronterface *"Stop called because of BLTouch error - restart with M999"*.

After it levels 9/9 points<sup>1</sup>, Pronterface shows a BLTouch error, the printer display shows print stopped, and the bed and nozzle setpoints had changed to zero. They both had already started cooling. I kept the start code simple just enough to get the print going.

I have no idea what the BLTouch error is but just that it caused two temperature settings to go to zero. Any help would be great!

---

<sup>1</sup> The 9/9 points I'm referring to is when I run `G29` and my config has 3x3 grid option selected so the `G29` probes 9 points total with the BLTouch.

Comment: Temperature is reset because printer (emergency) stops the print, I bet it is not correlated to the `G29` procedure. Please describe behaviour of the BT light during and after the process. How did you enable BL-Touch? from LCD?

Comment: @Greenonline Not sure how to close this but I managed to figure it out, decided to try moving the Z-axis wires from the BLTouch plug on the motherboard and plugged them into where the printers Z-axis wires plug in and that solved the problem. No more errors and the print continues now instead of shutting down after the G29 command.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if it had something to do with my Z-axis and BLTouch. When I unplugged the Z-axis on the printer, the extruder wouldn't lower, only raise; so I plugged it back in, and it moves in the right direction. The motherboard I'm using is a SKR E3 Mini V2 and the BLTouch is 3.1 On that version motherboard, the BLTouch plug has all 5 wires combined in one plug, whereas on other versions it has a three-wire plug for the BLTouch, and the wires for the Z-axis from the BLTouch have a separate two-wire plug with its own plug-in spot. But I've read about instances where users had to plug those two wires into the motherboard's default plug for the printer's Z axis which is usually unplugged. I decided to unpin the BLTouch Z-axis wires from the 5-wire plug and unpin the printer's Z-axis two wires and repin that plug with the Z-axis from the BLTouch and plug into the spot on the motherboard that is normally used by the printer's wires, and that fixed the problem. There's [information](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/firmware/V2.0) on GitHub that the board manufacturer posted about the issue, and thankfully that was my exact problem.